# What happened when use vector::reserve or vector::resize

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, resize

I'm user of C++14.
When I coded for sort two dimensional array using std::vector with compare fucntion.
But it didn't work as I thought, finally I found something weird things.
Let's see code below.

```
using namespace std;

int n;
vector<vector<int>> v;

bool cmp(const vector<int>& l, const vector<int>& r){
    return l[1] < r[1] ? true : l[0] < r[0];
}

int main() {
    scanf("%d", &n);
    v.resize(n, vector<int>(2));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        scanf("%d %d", &v[i][0], &v[i][1]);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << v[i][0] << ' ' << v[i][1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(Please ignore that I use `scanf` with `cout`. I'm doing on problem solving.)
And here is input

```
11
1 4
3 5
0 6
5 7
3 8
5 9
6 10
8 11
8 12
2 13
12 14
```

I expected that output is exactly same with input without `n`, but the output is

```
0 6
1 4
2 13
3 5
3 8
5 7
5 9
6 10
8 11
8 12
12 14
```

Also I found the weird point when I change

```
v.resize(n, vector<int>(2);
```

to

```
v.reserve(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        v[i].reserve(2);
```

`reserve` makes code right as I wanted.
I think I know the different with `reserve` and `resize` at `vector` but something is missing...

Would you teach me what is missing thing..?

Comment: Your code didn't compile because `meeting` is undeclared.

Comment: *"`reserve` makes code right as I wanted"* - Reserving doesn't add elements to the vector, only raw memory. You are interacting with vectors that aren't there.

Comment: Your `cmp` implementation doesn't obey strict weak ordering (I don't think).  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: resize changes the size of a vector, reserve doesn't. That's the thing you are missing. reserve allocates more space for the vector but does not change it's size.

Comment: Thank you for alll. I found bug in my logic for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your `cmp` function may not be what you want.
For example, it will judge `{0, 6}` as smaller than `{3, 5}`.
Try this instead:

```
bool cmp(const vector<int>& l, const vector<int>& r){
    return l[1] < r[1] ? true : (l[1] == r[1] && l[0] < r[0]);
}
```

or this:

```
bool cmp(const vector<int>& l, const vector<int>& r){
    return l[1] != r[1] ? l[1] < r[1] : l[0] < r[0];
}
```

Secondly, [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) won't change the number of elements in the vectors.
For this reason, you invoked *undefined behavior* by using out-of-range (nonexistent) elements and you got your result **by chance**.

Comment: Your right... It was just coincidence ◡̈ It was my misunderstood of vector::reserve. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the size of your inner container at compile time, maybe you want to use an `std::array` instead (or `std::pair` or even a small struct to have better member variables names). Also, don't forget for range-based loop, it's elegant and a safer approach when iterating on a container. Next, you could use a lambda for your compare function in the `std::sort` call. Global variables are also considered as a bad practice, since it broke the encapsulation rule.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> vec(n);
    for (auto& [x, y] : vec)
        std::cin >> x >> y;
    
    std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec), [](const auto& l, const auto& r)
        { return l[1] != r[1] ? l[1] < r[1] : l[0] < r[0]; });

    for (const auto& [x, y] : vec)
        std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You're answer is amazingly helpful, because I don't have code reviewer of C++ since I work with java actually. I code c++ program for my pleasure. Really really thank you for your answer! Have a nice day :)